# Ошибка AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python, discord, async-await, discord.py, python-3.9

Код:

```
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # Ошибку выдаёт если:
    if message.guild.id is not None:
        print("Hello world")
    # Либо если:
    if message.guild.id == 4148712772174:
        print("Hello world x2")
```

Суть в том что если сообщение бот получил в к себе в личку, и при этом я обратился к message.guild.id любым способом, то выдаёт ошибку.
Я даже пытался делать проверку на NoneType, но выдаёт всю ту же ошибку. Что делать?

Comment: попробуйте место `message.guild.id is not None` использовать `message.guild is not None`

Comment: и второй `if` должен быть в втором `if`'e

Comment: Это я для примера сделал в разных, щас проверю